# Como exibir o código fonte dentro da minha página PHP sem que ele seja interpretado?

Tags: php, editor

Galera, bom dia!

Estou fazendo um curso de PHP e de modo a deixar mais facil para consultas futuras, eu gostaria de criar uma pagina como se fosse uma biblioteca para que eu possa consultar trechos do código com comentários e como funciona aquele trecho, e para isso eu quero que o proprio código seja exibido na tela sem que seja interpretado, assim como funciona aqui no stack overflow.

Abaixo seque imagem do que exatamente quero, um interpretador que exibe o código, ja pesquisei mas não encontrei nada.

**Editor do Stack overflow**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exibindo na pagina sem ser interpretado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leia: [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta)

Comment: Basta escrever usando HTML. "<" não é um caractere válido em HTML, `&lt;` é o correto. O mesmo vale para todo caractere especial para o HTML, precisa da grafia correta.

Answer (score 1):

Substitui o caractere < com o código `&lt;` e > com `&gt;`.